# Google Map direction line

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this code that allows the user to enter two cities, and shows the location of the given inputs.  But what I want is to show as well the direction from the 1st city to the other.  How to do that?

Here is my practice code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQ8OCC8En5vNHod25Ov3Qs5E1v7NPRSsg&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        function initialize1() {

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 100.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }

        function initialize() {
            // add mapOptions here to the values in the input boxes.
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 100.644),
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            addAddress(document.getElementById('from').value);
            addAddress(document.getElementById('to').value);
        }

        function addAddress(place) {
            var address = place;
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    From: <input id="from" type="text" name="From"><br>
    To: <input id="to" type="text" name="To"><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="initialize()">View example (map-simple.html)</button>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DirectionsService in the Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions).  Here is an example from the documentation:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

and with text directions:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the "location" means the address you can use the direction renderer like below to get the direction.
First of all store the location address of the two markers into the two text boxes if you want to display the to and from address with id's #from and #destination then follow the below code

```
      $("#find").click(function () {
            starting = $("#from").val();
            finishing = $("#destination").val();
            $("#map").gmap3(
            {
                action: 'getRoute',
                options: {
                    origin: starting,
                    destination: finishing,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                },
                callback: function (results) {
                    if (!results) {
                        alert("returning")
                        return
                    };
                    $(this).gmap3(
                    {
                        action: 'addDirectionsRenderer',
                        options: {
                            preserveViewport: true,
                            draggable: false,
                            directions: results

                        }
                    }
                    );
                }
            })
        })
```

Comment: its not working.... got this error... $("#map").gmap3( is not a function..  I tried to changed that one to "#map_canvas"... but still got the same error... thanks

Comment: I have done it this is the working one actually I have implemented this module according to my need, like I will use one marker to find the from address and to address and use this to get the direction ....... :D

Comment: actually the code I have sent will work for gmap3 versions and other new versions you are not using that version so you have to do some changes while creating the markers just the syntax will change concept will remain the same

Comment: refer the code I have given which includes the html part also let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

Explanation : At first I created two markers of different locations and different data then after the dragend of any marker there will be infowindow that shows the address and two buttons start and finish. I think you have done upto this part .
So after this I used two text boxes which will be filled according to the start button or finish button clicked .
After this if the user clicks the find button this text boxes values are used to find the direction between the two markers 
Note: "here you can any marker for from or to only difference you have to maintain is to change the button clicked that is start or finish ....."
"You can even directly give the address in the text boxes and find the directions between them"
Here for whole manipulation I used gmap3 here is the code below that might help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = clear;
    function clear() {
        $("#from").val(null)
        $("#destination").val(null)
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var starting = "";
        var finishing = "";
        $("#find").click(function () {
            starting = $("#from").val();
            finishing = $("#destination").val();
            $("#map").gmap3(
            {
                action: 'getRoute',
                options: {
                    origin: starting,
                    destination: finishing,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                },
                callback: function (results) {
                    if (!results) {
                        alert("returning")
                        return
                    };
                    $(this).gmap3(
                    {
                        action: 'addDirectionsRenderer',
                        options: {
                            preserveViewport: true,
                            draggable: false,
                            directions: results

                        }
                    }
                    );
                }
            })
        })
        $("#map").gmap3({

            action: 'addMarkers',
            markers: [ //markers array
                {lat: 22.74, lng: 83.28, data: 'madhu' },
                { lat: 17.74, lng: 82.28, data: 'raghu' }
            ],
            map: { // this is for map options not for any markers
                center: [17.74, 83.28],
                zoom: 5
            },
            marker: {
                options: {
                    draggable: true
                },

                events: {// marker events
                    dragend: function (marker, event, data) {
                        var contentString = '<div id="main content">'
                            + '<input type="button" id="start" value="start" />'
                            + '<input type="button" id="finish" value="finish" />'
                            + '</div>';
                        //get address on click event
                        $(this).gmap3({
                            action: 'getAddress',
                            latLng: marker.getPosition(),
                            callback: function (results) {
                                var map = $(this).gmap3('get'),
                                infowindow = $(this).gmap3({ action: 'get', name: 'infowindow' })
                                if (infowindow) {
                                    content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : 'no address';
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                    infowindow.setContent(content + contentString);
                                }
                                else {
                                    content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : 'no address';
                                    $(this).gmap3({
                                        action: 'addinfowindow',
                                        anchor: marker,
                                        options: { content: content + contentString },
                                        events: {
                                            domready: function () {
                                                $("#start").click(function () {
                                                    alert("start clicked  " + content);
                                                    $("#from").val(content);
                                                    starting = content; 
                                                    check();
                                                })
                                                $("#finish").click(function () {
                                                    alert("finish clicked  " + content);
                                                    $("#destination").val(content);
                                                    finishing = content;
                                                })
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                            }

                        });
                    },
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is the html part for the above

```
 <div id="headinput">
            <input type="text" value="enter from" id="from" />
            <input type="text" value="enter destination" id="destination" />
            <input type="button" value="find" id="find" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id ="map"style="width: 100%; top: auto; left: auto; position: relative; height: 600px; float:left" ></div>
```

This is perfectly worked one I checked it in firefox browser........:D

Comment: Let me know if you are not clear with anything in the above concept....... :D @Jason

Comment: I think you didn't include the latest gmap3.js

Comment: Yes, but i don't think so I have downloaded the correct one.  I have downloaded the files from this site. http://www.ramoonus.nl/tag/google-maps/